# How can I file for unemployment as a US citizen living abroad?

Tags: us-citizens, unemployment-benefits

I am a US citizen and was working as US expat for an NGO based in Rockville, MD. All my taxes are paid to US and up to date with IRS.
I was terminated right before Covid-19 outbreak. I am still stuck with my family abroad. My question is how I can apply for unemployment benefits? I do not pay state taxes to Maryland, but all other federal taxes were withhold from my salary directly.

Comment: Where are you resident?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Doesn't matter. If resident outside Maryland, and covered by Mary's unemployment insurance program, application is still made to Maryland. See: FAQ #4 on http://www.labor.maryland.gov/employment/claimfaq.shtml#movedfrommd. The more germane question is _may the OP collect Maryland unemployment when the work was done outside the state?_ That question is unanswered by the FAQ.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica before asking that question I would ask whether the employee was even covered under Maryland's unemployment insurance program.

Comment: @phoog That's another way of phrasing the same question I put. While the OP had a MD employer, a quick run-through of the MD unemployment insurance webpages didn't present anything addressing it. I think one would have to examine the MD statutes (and, perhaps, MD administrative and/or legal cases...or a MD unemployment atty) to find the answer.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica another question to ask, of course, is whether he is entitled to unemployment benefits in his place of residence.

Comment: Yes. While anything's possible, I'd be surprised if any country (or political subdivision) offered UI coverage to a resident employed by an overseas firm. And here's more: even if the OP is entitled to MD UI coverage, how would the OP satisfy the MD requirement to be personally present for job interviews and UI in-office reviews?

Comment: Have the OP and employer been complying with tax and labor laws where the OP is employed? If so, the OP may well be entitled to unemployment pay there.

Comment: Good point. But in a developing economy, neither the existence of a UI program nor the NGO's participation is a slam dunk.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica: "Doesn't matter. If resident outside Maryland, and covered by Mary's unemployment insurance program, application is still made to Maryland." I don't think that's universally true. I believe that a US state's unemployment can only be collected if the person is presently in the US (in that state or another state), and authorized to work in the US, or the person is presently in Canada, and authorized to work in Canada. I do not believe this is true if the person is present in any other country.

Comment: One thing you'd need to check is whether you're required to periodically report to your local unemployment office.  Doing this from abroad might be cost-prohibitive.

Comment: @user102008 Do you have any support for your assertion that the applicant must be resident within the state? Maryland's FAQ specifically allows for applicants to be resident elsewhere, although the applicant must thereafter appear in MD for an interview and be available (presumably in MD, but not specified) for work and in-person reviews.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica: I never stated that the applicant must be resident within "the state". I stated that the applicant must be in the US or Canada.

Comment: @user102008 The MD apply-for-unemployment FAQ didn't show a requirement that the applicant be in MD or in the US. Where do you find this restriction?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica: In [this guide](https://www.dllr.state.md.us/employment/clmtguide/uiclmtpamphlet.pdf), at the bottom of page 13, it says "You are not eligible to continue filing for UI benefits if you move to another country. "

Comment: @user102008 Very good find. My previous conclusion from the FAQ was evidently in error. I take the Guide's text to say that moving out of the US or its territories makes the applicant unable to continue filing, unable to demonstrate compliance with job search requirements, and thus unable to receive UI benefits. One quibble: the Guide doesn't except Canada from the must-be-in-the-US requirement. Going north of the 49th Parallel seems to disqualify further MD UI participation.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica: Hmm, [the 2016 version](https://web.archive.org/web/20171005161251/http://www.dllr.state.md.us/employment/clmtguide/uiclmtpamphlet.pdf) of the pamphlet seems to include Canada (page 6): "You are not eligible to continue filing for  unemployment  insurance  benefits  if  you  move  to another country or United States territory, with the exception of Puerto Rico, Virgin Islands or Canada."

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica: but the [2017 version](https://web.archive.org/web/20200425132639/https://www.dllr.state.md.us/employment/clmtguide/uiclmtpamphlet.pdf) seems to exclude Canada (page 7): "You  are  not  eligible  to  continue filing for unemployment insurance benefits if you move to another country, with the exception of the United  States  territories:  Puerto  Rico,  Virgin  Islands,  Samoa, Guam, or the Northern Mariana Islands." I am not sure if the change was intentional.

Comment: @user102008 Ah! I didn't see that, was only reading later (pgs 11-13) in the 2016 version you originally cited, and didn't see the earlier (pg 6) Canada exclusion. But if the 2017 version omits the Canada exception, it seems likely that Canadian residence is now disqualifying.